# Ranking PHP e SQL, sem repetir registro do banco

Tags: php, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um ranking com `php` e `sql`, consigo listar os dados corretamente. No entanto, preciso fazer com que não apareça registros repetidos.

Meu código:

```
<?php
    include_once('conexao.php');
    $rank = "SELECT * FROM ranking ORDER BY pontuacao DESC LIMIT 0, 6";
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $rank);
    $i = 0;
    if(($query) AND ($query->num_rows != 0)){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

         $id_usuario = $row['id_usuario'];
         $pontos = $row['pontuacao'];
      }
    }
?>


<html>
<body>
<div style="background: lightgray;width: 120px;height: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 30px;">

          <h5><?php echo "id_usuario: ".$id_usuario." "."<br>pontos: ".$pontos; ?></h5> 
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php 

} else {
    echo "nem um registro encontrado!";    
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: edite e melhora sua pergunta. Coloque melhor seu código tbm

Answer (score 0):

Seria mais simples trazer na sua consulta ao banco já os valores desejados, evitando ter que fazer loops desnecessários no seu código PHP, assim você ganha tempo no carregamento da página e deixa seu código mais fácil de manter. Algo assim deve resolver seu problema:

```
$rank = "SELECT id_usuario, MAX(pontuacao) AS 'pontuacao_maxima' FROM ranking GROUP BY id_usuario";
```

Altere também a parte que imprime os dados, ela deve estar no corpo da página. Da forma como você colocou, seu código vai sempre imprimir o ultimo resultado, e esse não é o comportamento desejado.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "id_usuario: ". $row['id_usuario'] . " fez ". $row['pontuacao_maxima'] . " pontos";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sugiro que você faça deste jeito, pegue o bloco php com a estrutura `while` e coloque dentro do html, ficando assim:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="background: lightgray;width: 120px;height: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 30px;">
    <?php
        include_once('conexao.php');
        $rank = "SELECT * FROM ranking ORDER BY pontuacao DESC LIMIT 0, 6";
        $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $rank);
        $i = 0;
        if(($query) AND ($query->num_rows != 0)){
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

             $id_usuario = $row['id_usuario'];
             $pontos = $row['pontuacao'];

             echo "id_usuario: ".$id_usuario." "."<br>pontos: ".$pontos;
          }
        } else {
          echo "nem um registro encontrado!";    
        }
    ?> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

OBS: eu não testei, experimente fazer isso. Caso não resolva nada, venha e comente o problema.